# How to use cognito:username at http proxy integration of HttpApi of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I want to use the variable named  event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.cognito:username which is the result of JWT authorizer at the URI of http proxy integration of HttpApi(I mean not RestApi) of AWS , because I want to access the information of authorized user. The exposed api is like this.

https://xxxxxx.com/platform/pro/user/john

pro means production .
john is event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.cognito:username .

The management console said my input like this is error.
[https://xxxxxx.com/platform/${stageVariables.stage}/user/${event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.cognito:username}](https://xxxxxx.com/platform/$%7BstageVariables.stage%7D/user/$%7Bevent.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.cognito:username%7D)

I think : is NG.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question by accident. I guess you solved this in the meantime, but in case it's still relevant, you need to put `cognito:username` in quotes and brackets, so instead of `${event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.cognito:username}` use `${event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims['cognito:username']}`.